# How Kafka producers manage the connections

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to understand how the producers make connections and maintain them when producing a message onto Kafka.

Let's say we have a kafka cluster with broker1, broker2 and broker3 and three producers producer1, producer2 and producer3.

Now let's assume all three producers are producing messages at t1, t1+10 sec , t1 + 20 sec respectively, I've below questions.

1. If they are producing onto the same topic, will all of them use the same connection or each producer will have it's own connection?
2. If they are producing onto three different topics, then how many connections would be open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) depends entirely on your code. You can reuse one producer object to send to any number of topics

2) depends how many partitions each topic has. You'll effectively have one connection per producer * the number of partitions that your partitioner has calculated

Test for yourself with netstat

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does it mean, if I've 3 partitions in each topic, there would be 9 connections? if yes, I'm curious to know why would establish 9 connections if I'm producing only one message from a producer, why do we need 9 connections?

Comment: If you produce one message, there's at most two connections. 1 to the controller for the bootstrap request, second to the leader partition of a broker that the partitioner has calculated... Perhaps you should read the kafka site discussing the protocols

Comment: Sure, I'll read that. I didn't find any details in https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/. It would be great if  you  can point me any other documentation on the connections. Thanks a lot

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#theproducer? Of course it'll not say "N connections will be established"... https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/